# i want to do assign one leaves to all the employees

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

Is there a way to create one leave and assign to all employees in the same was as in alloction where odoo uses tags? 
In my case I want to do it with all employee without tags

```py
@api.multi
def appliquer(self):
    emp = self.env['hr.employee'].search([]).id
    res={}
    for rec in emp:
        for record in self.browse():
            vals = {    
                'name': record.name,
                'employee_id': rec.id,
                'holiday_status_id': record.type.id,
                'date_from': record.date_f,
                'date_to': record.date_t,
                'number_of_days_temp': record.nbr_days,
                'toapprouve':'true',        
                }
            res =  self.env['hr.holidays'].create(vals)     
       return  res
```

I get the error

> Expected singleton: hr.employee(......

Comment: please wrap your function inside code section so that we can have a better view.

Comment: can you please add self.ensure_one() inside your function.

Comment: it's not working
what s i want is to select all employee and with the loop in the list of id's i can create the leave to all of theme with my wizard

Answer (score 0):

You got an error because you tried to get `id` attribute from a recordset at line:

```
emp = self.env['hr.employee'].search([]).id
```

I think you forgot to remove `.id`.

Calling `browse` without an id will raise an error.

> > **[browse()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.browse)**
> >     Takes a database id or a list of ids and returns a recordset,

You are trying to create a leave for all employees and you need to run that code only one time for each employee, so remove the second loop then replace `record` with `rec`.